# Path variables aren't substituted when running tests using collection runner

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

I'm using Postman for testing of my REST APIs. Within URL I can use path variables like:

```
https://api.library.com/:entity/
```

and specify actual value using **Params** button. Everything works fine when testing using **Send** command. Variable **:entity** is substituted by provided parameter value.

But when I test same using Collection Runner then path variable isn't substituted even the value is present under Params. When I check URL on Results page it still shows original url:

```
https://api.library.com/:entity/
```

I found that I can put global variable in the path which seems to work but I'd prefer it to have it as path variable which gives me more flexibility (i.e. documenting variables).
Any idea, pls?